# Having trouble with UIView slide animation from left to right?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to animate 2 `UIViews`, UIView1 is present, and upon a button tap, UIView2 slides from right to left and occupies the screen, moving UIView1 out of the way.

That part I am able to achieve successfully with `slideLeftTransitionFromView`. However, upon a button tap again to slide UIView1 from left to right with `slideRightTransitionFromView`, UIView1 somehow disappears during the animation. UIView2 does slide successfully out of the way from left to right, but I cannot see UIView1.

I'm sure `slideRightTransitionFromView` follows similar logic as `slideLeftTransitionFromView`, but I'm having trouble getting it working.

Here's the 2 functions:

```
func slideLeftTransitionFromView(view: UIView, toView: UIView, duration: NSTimeInterval, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
{
    if let container = view.superview
    {
        // Final position of outgoing view
        let outgoingViewEndX = view.frame.origin.x - view.frame.size.width

        // Final position of incoming view (existing frame)
        let incomingViewEndX = view.frame.origin.x

        // Start point of incoming view -- at the right edge of the outgoing view
        let incomingViewStartX = view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.size.width

        // Distance traveled by outgoing view
        let outgoingDisplacement = view.frame.origin.x - outgoingViewEndX

        toView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(incomingViewStartX, toView.frame.origin.y)
        container.addSubview(toView)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { ()
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

                view.frame.origin.x = outgoingViewEndX
                toView.frame.origin.x = incomingViewEndX

                }, completion: {(complete: Bool) in

                    // If the outgoing view is still in onscreen, keep sliding until it's offscreen
                    if outgoingViewEndX + view.frame.size.width > 0 {

                        // Adjust the duration for the final animation based on the distance it has to travel in order to keep the same velocity.
                        let finalDuration = duration * Double((outgoingViewEndX + view.frame.size.width)/outgoingDisplacement)

                        UIView.animateWithDuration(finalDuration, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

                            view.frame.origin.x = -view.frame.size.width
                            }, completion: { (complete: Bool) in
                                completion?(complete)
                                view.removeFromSuperview()
                        })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completion?(complete)
                        view.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
            })
        })
    }
}

func slideRightTransitionFromView(view: UIView, toView: UIView, duration: NSTimeInterval, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
{
    if let container = view.superview
    {
        // Final position of outgoing view
        let outgoingViewEndX = view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.size.width

        // Final position of incoming view (existing frame)
        let incomingViewEndX = view.frame.origin.x

        // Start point of incoming view -- at the left edge of the outgoing view
        let incomingViewStartX = view.frame.origin.x - view.frame.size.width

        // Distance traveled by outgoing view
        let outgoingDisplacement = view.frame.origin.x + outgoingViewEndX

        toView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(incomingViewStartX, toView.frame.origin.y)
        container.addSubview(toView)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { ()
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

                view.frame.origin.x = outgoingViewEndX
                toView.frame.origin.x = incomingViewEndX

                }, completion: {(complete: Bool) in

                    // If the outgoing view is still in onscreen, keep sliding until it's offscreen
                    if outgoingViewEndX + view.frame.size.width < 0 {

                        // Adjust the duration for the final animation based on the distance it has to travel in order to keep the same velocity.
                        let finalDuration = duration * Double((outgoingViewEndX + view.frame.size.width)/outgoingDisplacement)

                        UIView.animateWithDuration(finalDuration, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

                            view.frame.origin.x = view.frame.size.width
                            }, completion: { (complete: Bool) in
                                completion?(complete)
                                view.removeFromSuperview()
                        })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completion?(complete)
                        view.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

It's likely something simple, but I can't see it. What seems to be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have probably declared the `UIView IBOutlet` as weak var

in `slideLeftTransitionFromView` calling `view.removeFromSuperview()` removes the view from view heirarchy and am pretty sure your view gets deallocated since it is a weak var and not part of the layout anymore.

> Therefore you dont see it when you try to add it again as subview
>   later on. Try making the var strong reference.

Comment: Commenting out `view.removeFromSuperview()` actually helped in seeing UIView1 again, however, upon calling `slideRightTransitionFromView`, instead of UIView2 sliding to the right, it immediately disappears and UIView1 immediately appears with no animation :(

Comment: log the frame values by how much value you are moving. this will require more debugging from your side

Comment: I have logged the values and it would seem (to me) that it is correct. I changed `outgoingViewEndX + view.frame.size.width` to `view.frame.size.width - outgoingViewEndX` within `slideRightTransitionFromView` because I thought that makes more sense. But it still produced the same results.

Comment: can you to the chat. you can see the link in my profile